# Delphi, how to make independent windows

Tags: delphi, user-interface, forms, tabs

I have an application that uses tabs like the Chrome browser. Now I want to be able to open more forms and not be limited to only one form. These forms should act the same but if I close main form all forms are closed. How can I make all forms be equal, so no matter which form I close it only closes that form and not exit application before all forms are closed? Any ideas?

[Image of my explorer](http://rmklever.com/2010-04-12_205033.png)

Kind Regards
Roy M Klever

Comment: A link to an annotated screenshot may help improve this question.  I'm not sure I follow the forms, tabs, main form, etc, descriptions.

Comment: A image link was added, not much need for comments and descriptions. I just want to be able to open more widows/forms like this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not too hard to do this, though it starts getting complicated quickly depending on how complete you want it to be.  Getting multiple modal dialogs to work independently is a ton of effort.

To start, you need to avoid Application.MainForm entirely.  Always use `Form := TMyForm.Create(Application)` instead of `Application.CreateForm(TMyForm, Form)`.  The later sets MainForm and you never want that to happen.

To make things shut down properly you'll need to do something like this in your form's `OnClose` event handler:

```
if Screen.FormCount = 1 then
  Application.Terminate;
CloseAction := caFree;
```

`Application.Run` relies on MainForm being assigned, so in your DPR replace that line with this loop:

```
repeat
  try
    Application.HandleMessage;
  except
    Application.HandleException(Application);
  end;
until Application.Terminated;
```

There are a couple of ways to handle the taskbar entry.

1. Single taskbar entry:  Set `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;` and the hidden TApplication handle will be used.  Clicking on the taskbar entry will bring all of the windows to the front.  You'll need to override `Application.OnMessage` or add a `TApplicationEvents` component, and watch for `WM_CLOSE` with the Msg.Handle = Application.Handle`.  In that case the user has right-clicked on the taskbar and selected **Close**, so you should close all the windows.
2. Multiple taskbar entries:  Set `Application.MainFormOntaskbar := True`.  Override your form's `CreateParams` method and set `Params.WndParent := 0;`.  Each taskbar entry will control that form.

There are probably a few other gotchas, but that's the basics.

---

As I said, making `ShowModal` and `TOpenDialog/TSaveDialog` working independently, so it only affects its parent form and so multiple dialogs can be open at once, is a ton of work, and I can't really recommend it.  If you're a masochist, here's the general steps:

1. Replace `TCustomForm.ShowModal` with a custom version.  Among other things, that routine disables all the other windows in the application, so you need to replace the `DisableTaskWindows/EnableTaskWindows` calls with `EnableWindow(Owner.Handle, False/True)` to just disable the parent form.  At this point you can open multiple dialogs, but they can only be closed in last-in, first-out order, because the calls end up being recursive.  If that's fine, stop here.

   There are two ways to work around that:

   1. Rather than making `ShowModal` blocking, have `StartModal` and `EndModal` routines that have the first bit and last bit of ShowModal's code and call an `OnShowModalDone` event when the dialog is closed.  This is kind of a pain to use, but is relatively easy to code and easy to make stable.
   2. Use the Windows [fiber routines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682402%28VS.85%29.aspx) to swap out the stack and start a new message loop.  This approach is easy to use, because `ShowModal` is blocking, so you call it like normal.  This is the approach we used in Beyond Compare.  **Don't do it.**  It's complicated to write, there *will* be stability issues for non-trivial applications because of incompatibilities with third party code (Windows global message hooks, TWebBrowser, .NET in shell extensions loaded by the browse dialog, etc), and if it's a cross-platform project, the Unix ucontext functions aren't safe to use either.
2. The common dialogs (TOpenDialog, TColorDialog, etc), have similar restrictions.  To make them only disable the parent form you need to override `TCommonDialog.TaskModalDialog` and replace the `DisableTaskWindows/EnableTaskWindows` calls there too.  They can't be made asynchronous like the regular Delphi dialogs above though, since they're blocking functions provided by Windows ([GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927%28VS.85%29.aspx), [ChooseColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646912%28VS.85%29.aspx), etc).  The only way to allow those to close in any order is to have each dialog run in a dedicated thread.  Windows can handle most of the synchronization to do that, as long as you're careful about accessing the VCL objects, but it basically involves rewriting large portions of `Dialogs.pas`.

Comment: Craig,

Thank you for a very good answear. I can see it was a little more complicated than I expected. Maybe time to do a little more thinking. This is good help for me. Thank you for taking your time to explain so thoroughly. My problem will be the modal dialogs, I have done some of this before but not in this setting. Well back into the thinking box.

Comment: +1 For describing a fully functional solution. However, there is a way that preserves Application.MainForm and is without the additional workarounds for ShowModal and the common dialogs; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988151/how-to-not-have-a-mainform-in-delphi/6230024#6230024).

Comment: @NGLN: I glossed over some of the details, and I think you misunderstood what it's trying to do. Each window is fully independent, so doing something in one shouldn't affect the others. If MainForm is assigned closing it will terminate the app.  If you use ShowModal and the common dialogs without the workarounds, all of the other windows are disabled.  Even if you fix that, you can only close them in the opposite order you opened them.  The full implementation  supports opening modal dialogs on any number of top-level forms simultaneously, and closing them in any order.

Comment: If modal behaviour isnt an issue: Simply hide the Mainform from the user, and instantiate other forms for user interaction. The last form closing may also close Mainform.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want that,

1) use a small, maybe hidden, MainForm and launch just the first childform at startup.

2) launch separate applications instead of Windows in the same process. This is what later Office version use.

Comment: Hi Henk,

Well to be honest I am looking at solution number 2 just need to find a way to sync data between seperate applications. As Craig pointed out, it is quite complicated managing everything in one application regarding dialogs and modal forms.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar StackOverflow question:
[Multiple app windows activation not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802279/multiple-app-windows-activation-not-working-correctly)

In my case I don't try to avoid the MainForm like Craig describes.  Instead, I hide the main window and all of my real windows are other non-modal forms.  I have been happy with how my application works, but Craig's approach may be simpler.

See my answer on the above question to see code samples for my approach and a few links with good background information.

Comment: Thanks Mark,

I think it is starting to get complicated allready. I think I gone try  the easiest way first then advance until I reach my goal, but it is good to see a lot of good answears. I need all information I can get.

Answer (score 1):

The first form created in a Delphi application is treated as the main form and the application terminates when this form gets closed. The obvious solution is to have a first form that is not one that gets closed by the user but rather one that is not visible to the user and gets closed only when all other forms have been closed.

I have not tried this, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is too late to be an answer but I bumped into the same problem. The solution I opted for is to extract `Application.ExeName` and pass it to a function like  `createProcess` or even `shellExecute`. So, now I have independent applications at the OS Level. I also needed different taskbar buttons for the different instances.